# Why is Base64 Upload Adapter in CKEditor 5 not converting images correctly?

Tags: javascript, angular, base64, ckeditor5

On my Angular 11 app I have a ckEditor component.  I want it to allow uploading images from the user's filesystem (and not just through links) which requires an upload adapter.  I customized my ckEditor build through https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/ and included the Image, ImageInsert, ImageUpload and Base64UploadAdapter (among many others).

I tried including the SimpleUploadAdapter plugin but it doesn't seem to be recognized on my system, giving me a error-filerepository-no-upload-adapter error, just as if I didn't include the plugin.
Therefore I included the 'Base64UploadAdapter, and this does encode images into my ckeditor data  to be uploaded to the server (which is fine).

The problem is that the base64 encodings are not valid.  ckeditor.js inserts spaces instead of +, for example and then the image becomes distored or doesn't display at all, giving an ERR_INVALID_URL.  Which makes me think the data is not URI-encoded.

In the ckeditor.js file I do see references to encodeURIComponent(), such as (piece of code from within large blob):
`sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;base64,".concat(btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(r)`

The strange thing is that in CkEditor's demo at https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/features/image-upload/base64-upload-adapter.html#demo , dropping an image into THEIR editor and ispecting it in the developer tools, it is encoded properly.  (I copied and pasted the resulting encoding into the browser and the image appeared all right).

- I searched Google and StackOverflow, no one seems to have this particular issue.
- I cleared the chrome cache and reinstalled the node_modules, didn't help.
- I don't see particular configurations for the Base64UploadAdapter plugin, (except limiting the user from uploading certain types of files, and since by default this plugin accepts various file types - limiting the user is not the answer here.  )

One thing I want to add: This is probably not related to the encoding issue, but just in case it is. The online builder came with a build folder (which I refer to in my code), but also with additional files that I did not touch or infer.  I wonder if there might be code there that I need to build or refer to:

1. a package.json file, including dependencies.  I did not install them because they cause duplicate installations in my node modules.  Is there a way to install unique ones, i.e. only dependencies that aren't currently configured?
2. a webpack.config.js which **I** did not refer to at all. (maybe it is picked up by the system, I don't know).

This is my my-component.html code:

```
<div>
    <ckeditor [config]="config" [editor]="editor" [(ngModel)]="data"></ckeditor>
</div>
```

and in my-component.ts:

```
import * as Editor from 'lib/assets/ckeditor64/build/ckeditor';

export class MyComponent{
    
    editor = Editor;
    config = {
        toolbar: {
            items: ['imageUpload','imageInsert',]
        },
        image: {
            toolbar: [
                'imageStyle:full',
                'imageStyle:side',
                '|',
                'imageTextAlternative'
            ]       
        
        }

    };
    data: string = '';
}
```

In short, I want to know why it might not be encoding my images correctly into Base64 and if there is possibly a workaround within the Angular framework that doesn't involve integrating my own upload adapter (since I am working with CkEditor's plugin itself anyway).
If there is other code I should include, please tell me.

Thank you very much in advance.